# Groups GLn(F) and PSLn(F)

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-groups

As J.S.Rose noted in his book "A Course on Group Theory" : There is a section of GLn(F) which is isomorphic to PSLn(F), n≥1, F is a field"?. I ask that "What can this section be?"

Comment: What do you mean by section?
There is no map from GL_n to PSL_n, only to PGL_n.

Comment: @Anton: "In group theory a section of a group G is a group that is (isomorphic to) a quotient group of a subgroup of G." (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_%28group_theory%29)

Comment: @Babak: SL_n(F) is a subgroup of GL_n(F), and SL_n(F)/Z(SL_n(F)) is isomorphic to PSL_n(F) (with Z denoting the center). 

Comment: In fact, if it is clear, since PSL_n(F) [n/=2, F an infinite field] is a non-abelian simple group, one can see that the GL_n(F) is a insoluble group. Maybe PGL_n is right instead of PSL_n??

Comment: "Someone" is correct. A section of a group $G$ is group of the form $H/K$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $K$ is a normal subgroup 
of $H$. A section therefore need be neither a subgroup nor a homomorphic image of $G$ itself."Someone" also correctly identifies the necessary subgroup $H$ and normal subgroup $K$ of $H$ in the case $G = {\rm GL}(n,F).$ The statement in Rose's book is accurate,
as long as one has a correct understanding of the meaning of the 
word "section" in this context. I do not see the relevance of the accepted answer below to the original question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No clue about the book but there is no non-trivial homomorphism from PSL(2,5) to GL(2,5). Use MAGMA or GAP to check it if it is not clear to you.